# ajax Django template nest，I am using ajax post form ，jango.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError:

Tags: javascript

Code:

```js
// make POST ajax call
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{% url 'robots:post_qrcode' %}",
    data: serializedData,
    success: function (response) {
        // on successfull creating object
        // 1. clear the form.
        $("#qrcode-form").trigger('reset');
        // 2. focus to url input 
        $("#id_url").focus();

        // display the newly qrcode to table.
        var instance = JSON.parse(response["instance"]);
        var fields = instance[0]["fields"];
        $("#my_qrcodes tbody").prepend(
            `<tr>
            <td><a href={% url "robots:qrcode_detail" ${instance[0]["pk"]||""} %}>${fields["url"]||""}</a></td>
            <td><a href=${fields["icon_url"]||""}>${fields["icon_url"]||""}</a></td>
            <td>${fields["page_view"]||""}</td>
            <td>${fields["count"]||""}</td>
            </tr>`
        )
    },
```

Exception:

> raise TemplateSyntaxError(
> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the
> remainder: '${instance[0]["pk"]||""}' from '${instance[0]["pk"]||""}'

How can I do?
Template syntax nested js

1.add `""`

```html
<td>
    <a href="{% url "robots:qrcode_detail" ${instance[0]["pk"]||""} %}>${fields["url"]||""}"</a>
</td>
```

2.add `${}`

```html
<td>
    <a href=${"{% url "robots:qrcode_detail" ${instance[0]["pk"]||""} %}>${fields["url"]||""}"}%</a>
</td>
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question. Are items 1 and 2 at the bottom ('add `""`' and 'add `${}`') things that you have tried but which have not fixed your problem, or are they solutions to your problem?